# Convert file path to URI in bash

Tags: bash, filenames

How can I convert a file path to an URI in the command-line?

**Example**:

```
/home/MHC/directory with spaces and ümläuts
```

to

```
file:///home/MHC/directory%20with%20spaces%20and%20%C3%BCml%C3%A4uts
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11876353/486504

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/296536/486504

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is using `urlencode` (install it on Ubuntu via `sudo apt-get install gridsite-clients`).

```
urlencode -m "$filepath"
```

will convert the path to an URI. The "file://" part of the URI will be left out, but you can easily add that via a bash one-liner:

```
uri=$(urlencode -m "$1"); echo "file://$uri"
```

or directly

```
echo "file://$(urlencode -m "$1")"
```

or

```
echo -n file://; urlencode -m "$1"
```

Many thanks to Michael Kjörling for the references!

Comment: Don't forget the quotes! You probably want `encodeduri=$(urlencode -m "$uri")` _with `$uri` in double quotes!_

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you, modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Fails for me, transforms "é" to "%FF%FF" (on Debian Buster)

Comment: Also didn't work for me, I got a bunch of `%FF` for cyrillic symbols.

Answer (score 6):

On CentOS, no extra dependencies needed:

```
$ python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<< "$my_url"
```

Comment: With `pathlib` module it could be done via `python -c 'import sys,pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]).resolve().as_uri())' "$my_url"`

Comment: `pathlib` is only available in Python 3, which is not installed by default on CentOS.

Comment: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python3

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the Perl module [URI::file](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/file.pm) directly from the command line:

```
$ path="/home/MHC/directory with spaces and ümläuts"
$ echo $path | perl -MURI::file -e 'print URI::file->new(<STDIN>)."\n"'
file:///home/MHC/directory%20with%20spaces%20and%20%C3%BCml%C3%A4uts
$
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `echo $path | perl -MURI::file -E 'say URI::file->new(<>)'` with Perl 5.10 (from year 2007) or newer

Answer (score 3):

Rockallite gave a good answer, but I didn't want to type that every time.

I made a reusable bash function to do this called "file2url". To see where to save bash functions, take a look at this [thread on SO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344557/where-can-i-put-a-user-defined-shell-function).

```
file2url () {
    python -c "import sys, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(input()).resolve().as_uri())" <<< $1
}
```

This assumes that you have a python3 installed with the name "python".

Comment: `sys` doesn't seem to be used

Answer (score 0):

You can pass path as argument to the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs

const { Gio } = imports.gi;

let path = Gio.File.new_for_path(ARGV[0]);
let uri = path.get_uri();
print(uri);
```

To convert from uri to path use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs

const { Gio } = imports.gi;

let uri = Gio.File.new_for_uri(ARGV[0]);
let path = uri.get_path();
print(path);
```